# Trying to order LINQ results

Tags: c#, linq, entity

To one of my tables I added a `sortOrder`.  I now need to update this query to respect the `sortOrder` authority!

Here is my current query:

```
var HTMLdocs = db.ProcedureDocs.Where(m => m.Procedures.Processes.processID == id && m.Document.html != null && m.Document.approvedBy != null).Select(m => m.Document);
```

The table that has sortOrder is `Procedures`.

How can I get the above query to return results that are ordered by sortOrder.

Here is the table structure.

```
Processes can have 0 or many Procedures.
Document can have 0 or many ProcedureDocs.

ProcedureDocs has a foreign key to Procedures on procedureid.
```

I somehow need to grab a collection of Document that somehow respects the order found in the Procedures table.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var HTMLdocs = db.ProcedureDocs
    .Where(m => m.Procedures.Processes.processID == id && 
                m.Document.html != null && 
                m.Document.approvedBy != null)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Procedures.sortOrder)
    .Select(m => m.Document);
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var HTMLdocs = 
    from m in db.ProcedureDocs
    where m.Procedures.Processes.processID == id && 
          m.Document.html != null && 
          m.Document.approvedBy != null
    orderby m.Procedures.sortOrder
    select m.Document;
```

Comment: I think `m.Procudures` is a collection (because of *0 or more*)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I thought that initially (because it's plural), but OP's current query uses `m.Procedures.Processes.processID == id`. If the current code compiles at all, it probably isn't a collection.

Comment: Didn't notice that. But that's why correct naming is a key in writing good code...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek How should it have been named?  The Procedures table houses a collection of Procedures.  Should I have named it Procedure?

Comment: If it's just a single `Procedure` from `Procedures` table then yes, the property should be called `Procedure`.

Comment: @JamesWilson If the property is a references to a single procedure, call it `Procedure`. The entity set can be named `Procedures` because that houses a collection of many procedures.

Comment: I'm new to Entity and Database design so forgive me for diving deeper into this.  I think I just misunderstand, but I would like to learn it better.  If I rename the above Procedures to Procedure it errors out.  My Table is named Procedures, the Model is named Procedures.  In this instance I only need a single Procedure.  Maybe I should have named the model Procedure since it can only hold a single procedure in this instance then if I did ICollection<Procedures> Procedures in that case?

Comment: @JamesWilson The model should be named `Procedure`. If a property is a single instance, it should be named `Procedure`. If a property references a collection of procedures, it should be named `Procedures`, like this `ICollection<Procedure> Procedures`. Of course, the code would work even if you named the property `_prop1`, (and mapped it correctly to the DB) but using semantic variable names reduces confusion and makes your code more maintainable.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense, I'll try and do better with that going forward.  I'm afraid back tracking might not be an option currently.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var HTMLdocs = db.ProcedureDocs
    .Where(m => m.Procedures.Processes.processID == id 
       && m.Document.html != null && m.Document.approvedBy != null)

    .OrderBy(x=>x.Procedures.sortOrder)
    .Select(m => m.Document)
```